# What is the alternate way to ng-repeat in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Generally ng-repeat is used to represent the objects and arrays in the view from the controller.It is used for repeating each element in the group of data.Here I want to know the alternate way for representing the group of data in the view without using ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the answer is dependent on situation in which you provide solutions anyway,

As per my development experience ng-repeat is good if you data is very less.and if data is heavy the performance of ng-repeat reduces considerable amount.

Inorder to solve above problem we can go for custom directives

Here are some of the directives which you can look for getting some idea

[AngularJS ng-repeat Alternative Approach](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1101082/AngularJS-ng-repeat-Alternative-Approach)

This document will give all step by step approach to create custom directives.

> This is about alternative approach to ng-repeat to handle heavy data
>   binding with better page performance. This article will provide
>   insights of how to replace particular ng-repeat with particular data.

[AngularJS directive for much more quicker lists rendering](https://github.com/allaud/quick-ng-repeat)

A custom directive you can add and you can customize based on your requirements with following features

> - Shallow list watch (ngRepeat uses deep watch)
> - Animations support
> - Special service to cause list render outside of digest cycle
> - Smooth scrolling even on heavy compited lists (check example)
> - About 200% performance boost
> - Still hesitating? Try to scroll page with ng-repeat list and a page      with quick-ng-repeat

Apart from this i can go for some solutions such as pagination lazy loading etc to improve performance

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat is good to use when you don't have a large amount of data. There is an advantage using ng-repeat, whenever you use **track by $index**, it will do some hashing, and when it encounters a similar kind of element as you update the model properties, it won't recalculate the layout for that particular element.Behind the scenes, ngRepeat adds a $$hashKey property to each task to keep track of it.

But ng-repeat is not the right thing to use when you have large datasets as it involves heavy DOM manipulations. And you should consider using ng-repeat with pagination.

You can consider using transclusion inside a custom directive, to achieve the behavior you are looking for without using ng-repeat.